# Declaring global unions in C

Tags: c, global-variables, unions

I am unsure how to declare a global union in C.  Below is my code (all of which is outside of main).

```
typedef union{
    int iVal;
    char* cVal;
} DictVal;
struct DictEntry{
    struct DictEntry* next;
    char* key;
    DictVal val;

    int cTag;
};

DictVal find(char* key);

int main()
{
    struct DictEntry dictionary[101];
    //printf("Hello");
}

DictValue find(char* key)
{
  DictVal a;
  a.iVal = 3;
  return a;
}
```

With this, I receive the error:

```
test.c:35: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘find’.
```

How can I declare the union in a way that I can use it as a return type for a function?

Thank you in advance!
Andrew

Comment: Shouldn't that read 
typedef union DictVal{
        int iVal;
        char* cVal;
    } DictVal; ?

Comment: Are you sure?  That snippet alone compiles fine.

Comment: @blueberryfields - No, it's just an anonymous union being `typedef`-ed into a name.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @blueberryfields: either way, it results in the same error.

Comment: @Tim Post: gcc on Ubuntu

Comment: @Andrew - Can you post the entire file? I am using gcc 4.4.1 on Ubuntu 9.10 and I can't reproduce your problem (compiled with -Wall without incident, even tried -std=c89)

Comment: maybe there is something before the declaration of your union that is not correct? code looks ok as is.

Comment: @Tim Post: OK, I edited the post to contain the whole file.  There is nothing before the union typedef.

Comment: Looks like a simple typo: DictVal is not the same as DictValue.

Comment: Not related but main should return a value.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you Ralph.  I was thrown off by where the error was located, I didn't even notice that was a typo.

Comment: @Raph - you should have made that an answer :)

Comment: @Andrew - You need some sleep :) It's @Raph , not @Ralph :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've typo'ed.

There's a `DictVal` typedef but you tried to use `DictValue` on the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Spelling error.

You declared:

```
 typedef union{
     int iVal;
     char* cVal;
 } DictVal;
```

but are trying to use

```
 DictValue find(char* key)
 {
   DictVal a;
```

Replace DictValue with DictVal.

Also make main return something. Normally it should be 0.

God bless!

Comment: Sadly, C99 codified the exemption that C++98 also gives to main(); it does not have to explicitly return a value and exiting from the end of main() is equivalent to return 0 or EXIT_SUCCESS. But I agree, it is better to use an explicit return.

Comment: Oh really? But shouldn't main() be declared as void, then? Also, then my gcc version is not compliant (or has this flag disabled in the IDE options) because it returns 1 with that code.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - The standard also specifies `gets()` but that doesn't mean you should use it ever.

Comment: @Chris: and strtok() and strncat() and ... yes, just because it is in the standard does not mean you have to use it.  Trinidad: no, `main()` has to be defined returning an `int`, and it may take either no arguments or two arguments and be compliant; anything else is not standard, but may also be legal if your implementation documents that it is legal.  Did you compile with `-std=c99` or some other setting?  I compiled `int main(){}` with `gcc -std=c89` and got 32 as the exit status; I compiled the same code with `gcc -std=c99` and got the exit status 0.  That is pretty compliant-looking to me.

Comment: No, declaring `void main` is *always* undefined behavior. The point Jonathan was making was that `main` implicitly returns 0 if execution reaches the end of the body without a `return` statement. But the return type must always be `int`.